# Почему алгоритм Дейкстры не работает для графов с отрицательными ребрами?

Tags: алгоритм, математика

Условно есть такой граф, [image: введите сюда описание изображения].

Вот код поиска кратчайшего пути по алгоритму Дейкстры.
`

```
def find_lowest_cost_node(costs):
    lowest_cost = float("inf")
    lowest_cost_node = None
    for node in costs:
        cost = costs[node]
        if (cost < lowest_cost) and (node not in processed):
            lowest_cost = cost
            lowest_cost_node = node
    return lowest_cost_node

graph = {}
graph["Start"] = {}
graph["Start"]["a"] = 5
graph["Start"]["b"] = 0
graph["a"] = {}
graph["a"]["b"] = -7
graph["b"] = {}
graph["b"]["fin"] = 35
graph["fin"] = {}

costs = {}
costs["a"] = 5
costs["b"] = 0
costs["fin"] = float("inf")

parents = {}
parents["a"] = "Start"
parents["b"] = "Start"
parents["fin"] = None


processed = []
node = find_lowest_cost_node(costs)
while node is not None:
    cost = costs[node]
    neighborts = graph[node]
    for n in neighborts.keys():
        new_cost = cost + neighborts[n]
        if costs[n] > new_cost:
            costs[n] = new_cost
            parents[n] = node
    processed.append(node)
    node = find_lowest_cost_node(costs)
    
print(costs["fin"])
print(parents)
```

`
Я так полагаю, что  по идеи алгоритма, стоимость fin - равняется 35, т.к узел C был выбран первым, после чего был обработан узел D, где в хеш таблице costs по ключу fin было записано 35. Следующим узлом был выбран B, где мы обновили стоимость С, но не D. Поэтому стоимость D по прежнему осталась 35. Но мы же обновили родителя для узла C, и в итоге получилось вот так [image: введите сюда описание изображения].

И на сколько я понимаю, мы можем правильно восстановить по таблице родителей стоимость? Или я где-то что-то путаю?

Comment: "На пальцах" примерно так... Алгоритм основан на том, что, грубо говоря, там, где уже побывали - больше не будем. И что чем дальше идем, тем больший суммарный вес - именно поэтому нам не нужно возвращаться: ничего лучше, чем есть, уже не будет. А ребра с отрицательным весом эти правила нарушают - может оказаться, что если воспользоваться ребром с отрицательным весом и вернуться в уже просмотренную вершину, то вес пути к ней окажется меньше. Что противоречит идее в основе алгоритма.

Comment: В графе с отрицательными весами понятие пути минимального веса может быть не определено. Это не зависит от алгоритма решающего задачу. Сам граф так (может быть) устроен, что нельзя сказать про какой-то путь - "это путь минимального веса". Пока это так, никакой алгоритм не может решить задачу, так как он будет искать то чего нет. Определитесь что такое путь минимального веса в вашем примере, тогда можно будет говорить находит ли конкретный алгоритм именно его.

Comment: "после чего был обработан узел D" - это не так. Дейкстра должен будет обработать D последним. Путь до B короче он и будет обработан следующим после C. Затем С обновится до -2. Затем обработается D.